# Android: Where is the datebase with phone calls stored?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm searching for the datebase in which all phone calls (metadata) are stored.

Normally I can find the databases at `/data/data/com.{name-of-app}/databases/databasefile.db`. I searched through many folders, but I didn't find any databasefile for the phone calls.

So where is this database? Or if there is no such database, where/how is the list of phone calls stored?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: NOT off topic. A programmer can have many uses for this information.  android.stackexchange.com  is for people USING android, not programming.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's Off-topic. 
I was not sure about it, because I need this database to analyse it – so it's not "using android" (nor really (app-)programming).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the list here:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

→ "main" → "calls".

Answer (score 1):

You won't have to parse database files. You can read the callLog like this:

```
 Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
 Cursor curse = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, null);
String num= curse.getString(curse.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
```

Please check the CallLog.Calls documentation. You can find all options you've got here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

Comment: Your solution will work for an App, but I need the real database to analyse it. (will copy it with "adb pull")


Maybe my question was not clear enough in this point.

Comment: I guess there is no rule for the .dbs location. This will depend on your phone model and android version. Your database name can also change. Maybe you should use grep

Comment: I had a look at every entry in all databases and found it at /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db → main → calls.